# Executing Classic-Resource-Finder.sh on EC2 Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How can I execute the [Classic-Resource-Finder.sh](https://github.com/aws-samples/ec2-classic-resource-finder/blob/main/Classic-Resource-Finder.sh) script on Linux?

This script searches for EC2 classic resources on all regions that support EC2 classic.

I've already installed EC2 Linux 2 on AWS. AWS CLI is installed by default and I installed JQ as well.

I haven't found a way for a command that will allow me to execute the script from GitHub.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For running the remote script, without creating a local copy:

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws-samples/ec2-classic-resource-finder/main/v1.0/Classic-Resource-Finder.sh | bash
```

The above command triggers [`wget`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) to download the file, with the output flag set to `-` to write the file's content (script) to standard output (`STDOUT`).

You can then simply pipe it to `bash` to run the script.

---

#### For running a local copy of the script:

```
chmod +x Classic-Resource-Finder.sh
bash Classic-Resource-Finder.sh
```

The 1st [`chmod +x`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) command makes the script executable for your current Linux user.

The 2nd command runs the script using the `bash` shell.

Comment: Thanks will check it out. If the file is already on the server (just copied it), how do I execute it directly or I need to make something with AWS CLI to make this script work corretly?

Comment: @IdanShechter Updated the answer - the execution of the script has nothing to do with the CLI; the CLI is called from within the script :)

Comment: the link does not work for me. This one is working https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws-samples/ec2-classic-resource-finder/main/v1.0/Classic-Resource-Finder.sh

Comment: @casper updated thank you